# Novel that is about robots fighting humans and dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, novel, clones, illustrated-story

This book I think came out between 2006-2008 and I remember that the whole book was illustrated. Sadly I have no idea who the author is. I remember the story fairly well.

The story starts out with a young man waking up inside some kind of pod but with no memory of his name or his past. He steps outside and he is in a lush green jungle and if I remember right he has a little robot companion that flies around him and alerts him about whatever dangers or info he might need or asks about. Shortly after coming out of his pod other robots come after him but they are hostile and are trying to kill him.

As he is running away from the robots he jumps across a big gap that no human would have been able to jump across and makes him begin to wonder about himself but doesn't stop for long to question what just happened since the robots are after him. My memory gets a bit hazy here but as he continues on he meets a women and few other humans as well I think and dinosaurs but these dinosaurs can actually talk if I remember right and can understand humans with some kind of head piece.

The humans and dinosaurs don't really trust him though and take him as a kind of prisoner sort of. They walk to a camp or post of some kind where there are other dinosaurs and humans who live together and he finds out that they are basically at war with robots. My memory again gets kinda hazy but along the way he feels some kind of connection to the robots. In the end he finds out that he is basically a clone of an actual human and finally remembers his name and his past and that he can control every single robot so then making him able to put a stop to the war.

Comment: Possibly related: [Post-apocalypse book/short story about a man who is a clone of one of the last humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/195280/98028) guy with amnesia wakes up in a jungle, has "abilities", talking animal acting as a guide (could match the robot companion), eventually discovers he's a clone (similar timeframe too)

Answer (score 3):

Is it the book [Robota](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?157093)?

> An elaborate study in world-building that traces a human's journey through a preindustrial civilization, Robota explores the relationship between nature and technology. The hero, Caps, awakens with amnesia in a fantastic world of dinosaurs and talking animals — a land of enchantment dominated by giant robots and their sadistic general, Kaantur-Set, who is bent on human genocide. With the help of Juomes, a yeti-like hunter-beast, Caps must battle the tyrannical robots and rediscover his true identity.

[image: Cover of "Robota" showing three skeletal robots with guns and capes]

More details on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robota) and [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/287090).

Comment: This answer would also be improved if you could cite a source that shows Caps is a clone.