# Post-apocalypse book/short story about a man who is a clone of one of the last humans

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

In this story, a man wakes up with no memory in a teleported chamber. Outside he finds a jungle/forest of a destroyed city with no human life. He meets a talking animal that becomes his guide and hints to his past and abilities. The man learns that he is an augmented human or cyborg capable of great strength and that he is a clone of one of the last humans who is currently maintaining the last of humanity's knowledge, despite a near total extinction.

I read this over a decade ago, so at this point I'm not sure if it was just a dream.

Comment: Were there robots and/or dinosaurs? There was a similar question some time ago... [Novel that is about robots fighting humans and dinosaurs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194991/98028) searches for a guy waking up in a pod in a jungle, can jump further than any human, and the main character figures out he's a clone

Comment: The beginning matches up, but it looks like nobody has been able to i.d. the book yet. Thanks for pointing out the post for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it the book [Robota](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?157093)?

> An elaborate study in world-building that traces a human's journey through a preindustrial civilization, Robota explores the relationship between nature and technology. The hero, Caps, awakens with amnesia in a fantastic world of dinosaurs and talking animals — a land of enchantment dominated by giant robots and their sadistic general, Kaantur-Set, who is bent on human genocide. With the help of Juomes, a yeti-like hunter-beast, Caps must battle the tyrannical robots and rediscover his true identity.

[image: Cover of "Robota" showing three skeletal robots with guns and capes]

More details on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robota) and [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/287090).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is Caps a clone?  Does he have cybernetic augmentations?

Comment: That's it!  I've done a quick skim of the book, and it matches what I remember and then some.  Thank you very much.